# Java Abstract Factory - Singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, abstract-factory

I need to create an example to explore Java World and take a one step more ahead.

I want to implement an example of an Abstract Factory. However I want to concrete factories must be served as singletons!

Could you please show me a simple implementation and an example usage?

I have limited knowledge of Abstract Factory Pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ? If knowledge is limited then google about it and learn. Don't expect any one to write the code for ya !

Comment: Have you tried at least google/wiki Abstract Factory Pattern?

Comment: Of course I'll do that. However I just thought the professionals in stackoverflow help me to jump very very fast. I was wrong apparently.

Comment: Well, they do @TimTuckle but they like to see some effort. Maybe post some code that you started with. Even if you think it's crappy.

Comment: From your question it is not completely clear what you want to achieve. A factory abstracts from the instantiation of a particular class, as it can serve a "family", or a set of classes, respectively. If you are going to create an abstraction of a factory, an "abstract Factory" you would further abstract to create a factory that creates a factory. From real world the factory would create, say different kinds of pianos, and the abstract factory would create projects that can create factories for music instruments. Are you sure you want to have such a factory producing instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AbstractFactory {

    private static Foo fooSingleton;
    private static Bar barSingleton;

    private AbstractFactory() {

    }

    public static AbstractFactory getSingletonInstance(string type) {
        if(type == "foo"){

            if (fooSingleton == null) {
                fooSingleton = new Foo();
            }
            return fooSingleton;
        }
        {{add additional cases for other types here}}
    }
}
```

Comment: To minimize complexity, you could even drop the lazy instantiation of the singletons. Mind that the given snippet is not thread-safe!